# Laravel API ResourceCollection doesnt works

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

i would like to know how to get work API call with ResourceCollection

Error :

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$name
```

my product method :

```
 public function index()
{
    return ProductCollection::collection(Product::all());
}
```

my collection :

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    //return parent::toArray($request);
    return [
        "name" => $this->name,
        "price" => $this->price,
        "href" => [
            "link" => route("product.show", $this->id)
        ]
    ];
}
```

tryed it just by Resourse ( not ResourceCollection ) just modifed method call and its was working but i need know how to fix ResourceCollection `return new ProductResource($product);`

error snap :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ProductCollection inherits ResourceCollection and not a Resource, so $this is not the model but the collection. If you want to mutate each element of the collection you can use the map function like that:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return $this->map(function($product) {
        return [
            "name" => $this->name,
            "price" => $this->price,
            "href" => [
                "link" => route("product.show", $this->id)
            ]
        ];
    });
}
```

Comment: why we need to loop it after all if we are using the ResourceCollection instead of JsonResource? Something is really confusing here...

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class ProductCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
```

to

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class ProductCollection extends Resource
{
```

Answer (score 0):

## create two resources

### for single resource and collection resource

- php artisan make:resource ProductResource
- php artisan make:resource ProductCollection or
- php artisan make:resource Product --collection

#### then go to your controller

`use App\Http\Resources\ProductCollection;
use App\Http\Resources\ProductResource;
// for single collection resource in   
return new ProductCollection(Product::all()); //or
return ProductResource::collection(Product::all());
//for single resource
return new ProductResource(Product::findOrFail($id));`


[docs official](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources)

Comment: please, change your answer format for more readability.